# using jquery updated version in user edit page

Tags: javascript

With jquery update module  I can use newer JQUERY version in my pages and also in admin pages I use another version, `1.9` for pages and `1.5` for admin pages,my question is DRUPAL know user edit page ( `user/uid/edit`)  as admin page, how can I use  updated version of JQUERY in user edit page?

I did something like

```
function mymodule_js_alter(&$js) {
  //$javascript['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'jquery_update') . '/jquery.js';

  if(preg_match('/user\/\d*\/edit/', current_path())){
    //ym($js);
    //there is exist 1.9.1 jquery file
     $path = libraries_get_path('jquery').'/jquery-1.9.1.min.js';
  // Copy the current jQuery file settings and change
  $js[$path] = $js['misc/jquery.js'];

  // Update necessary settings
  $js[$path]['version'] = 1.9;
  $js[$path]['data'] = $path;
  // Finally remove the original jQuery
  unset($js['misc/jquery.js']);
  }
}
```

also

```
function mymodule_js_alter(&$js) {


  if(preg_match('/user\/\d*\/edit/', current_path())){
     $path = libraries_get_path('jquery').'/jquery-1.9.1.min.js';
  // Copy the current jQuery file settings and change
  $js['sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'] = $path;
  }
}
```

but not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: First check the path, and then replace the JavaScript file.

```
function mymodule_js_alter(&$js) {
  if (preg_match('/user\/\d*\/edit/', current_path())) {
    $js['sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js']['data'] = 'sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js';
  }
}
```